# How to check if the user is logged in using knockout

Tags: javascript, php, knockout.js

Is there any way to know if the user is logged in using knockout js? How can I get the user's data?
I tried this code,

```
var userId = '<%=HttpContext.Current.Session["user_session"] %>';
    alert(userId);
```

I put it in a view model. But it is not working.

Here is the requested PHP code,

```
public function login($email,$pass)
{
   try
   {
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE emailadd=:email LIMIT 1");
      $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$email));
      $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
      {
         if(password_verify($pass, $userRow['password']))
         {
            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['id'];
            return true;
         }
         else
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }
   }
```

And here is the js code,

```
function homeViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    var userId = '<%=HttpContext.Current.Session["user_session"] %>';
    alert(userId);
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Please include your PHP code as well.. To improve the response you get from your questions, having consider doing such things as posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), making your question clear in the title ,[adding necessary tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)... and [heading on over to the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Session` where is this come from, copy-pasting without understanding?

Comment: I saw it in some stackoverflow questions. One person said that need to assigned the HttpContext.Current‌​.Session into a javascript variable. So I tried to put it in my view model.

Comment: @John that's what i was talking about `HttpContext...` came form an asp.net anwer and you are try to use it with php

Comment: Ok. So is there other way to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `homeViewModel` is defined in an external javascript file then you can't execute php.

You'll have to do something similar to the following (Not Tested).

1) index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.currentUser = '<%=HttpContext.Current.Session["user_session"] %>'
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="my-vm.js"> 
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p data-bind="text: user"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

2) my-vm.js

```
function homeViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.user = ko.observable(window.currentUser);
    return self;
}
ko.applyBindings(new homeViewModel());
```

Having said this you'll want to consider how you manage the scope. Attaching arbitrary variables to `window` isn't a great idea going forward.